# Can't Deploy Web Service Listener/Sender in Mirth Connect 2.0

Tags: web-services, mirth

I'm currently running Mirth 2.0.1.5164 with JDK 1.6 update 10 on Windows XP SP3. I kept getting this error every time I want to deploy a Web Service Listener/Sender channel:

[2011-04-11 09:31:11,947]  ERROR (com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.MuleEngineController:207): Error registering channel.
org.mule.providers.FatalConnectException: ReconnectStrategy "org.mule.providers.SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy" failed to reconnect receiver on endpoint "ws://127.0.0.1:8041"
    at org.mule.providers.SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.doConnect(SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.java:34)
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractConnectionStrategy.connect(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:67)
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver.start(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:391)
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractConnector.registerListener(AbstractConnector.java:508)
    at org.mule.impl.model.AbstractModel.registerListeners(AbstractModel.java:231)
    at org.mule.impl.model.AbstractModel.registerComponent(AbstractModel.java:187)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.MuleEngineController.registerChannel(MuleEngineController.java:327)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.MuleEngineController.deployChannels(MuleEngineController.java:201)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.servlets.EngineServlet.doPost(EngineServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:615)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:677)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:568)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.mortbay.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.mortbay.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)Caused by: org.mule.providers.FatalConnectException: ReconnectStrategy "org.mule.providers.SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy" failed to reconnect receiver on endpoint "ws://127.0.0.1:8041"
    at org.mule.providers.SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.doConnect(SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.java:34)
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractConnectionStrategy.connect(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:67)
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver.connect(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:348)
    at org.mule.providers.SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.doConnect(SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.java:32)
    ... 22 moreCaused by: org.mule.providers.ConnectException: Initialisation Failure: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.jaxws.AcceptMessage is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver.connect(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:362)
    at org.mule.providers.SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.doConnect(SingleAttemptConnectionStrategy.java:32)
    ... 25 moreCaused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error: Wrapper class com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.jaxws.AcceptMessage is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(Unknown Source)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.WebServiceMessageReceiver.doConnect(WebServiceMessageReceiver.java:125)
    at org.mule.providers.AbstractMessageReceiver.connect(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:355)
    ... 26 more

The channel I used worked perfectly at Mirth 1.8, but when I deployed it in 2.0 it kept getting this error, and I had checked with netstat to make sure the port i used wasn't occupied. I've tried adding JAXWS and JAXB to the custom-lib but it's also not working (tried this solution from the Mirth Support forum). One more thing, I used the default service for the Web Service Listener. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

extra note: I haven't uninstall the 1.8 version yet, since it is still used by the current program my company developed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old but I figured I'd answer it anyway.  I think this is the same issue my team encountered:

There was an issue in Mirth 2.0 -- after the service is restarted or the machine rebooted, it tries to contact the WSDL **one time**.  If your WSDL is not discoverable, you get this error deploying the channels.

We verbally confirmed with Mirth's support team that it was a known issue but unfortunately I can't find it in their issue tracker.  I don't know if it's fixed.   I would try with the latest version, or alternately make sure your WSDL can be found by Mirth.